# Can Chrome Dev tools help figure out Angular component name?

Tags: angular, google-chrome-devtools

Assuming that I have the Angular source code for the application, how can I use Chrome Developer tools to figure out the name of a specific Angular component?

For example, let's say the application makes use of a popup dialog box and I want to find the source code for the dialog box. Can Chrome Developer tools help me figure out then name of the component?

So far I have been drilling down the elements tree in Chrome Dev tools and when I think I have the element for the dialog box I search the angular code for the HTML. However, I often get false matches and it is time consuming. I was wondering if there was a better way I might not be familiar with.

Comment: Why don't you use [Augury](https://augury.rangle.io/)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Use Augury:

You can use **[Augury](https://augury.rangle.io/)**. It's a Chrome and Firefox Extension Managed by the folks at [**Rangle**](https://rangle.io/).

Once you've installed it, just open Chrome Dev Tools(assuming you're using Chrome), and it will be visible as one of the Tabs in the tools.

You can simply select a Component from the Web page and it is going to accurately mark the Component that you were on as of then.

[image]

### Use `ng.probe($0).componentInstance`

You can select a component using the Element Selector from the Elements Tab. And then go to the Console Tab, and type in:

```
ng.probe($0).componentInstance
```

This is going to give you the Component Instance of the recently selected Component along with its name and then you can look for it accordingly. Something like this:

[image]

**NOTE:** There methods would only work in DEV mode.

Comment: Note that this only works for apps built in development mode.

Comment: @IngoBürk, noted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `ng.probe($0).componentInstance` doesn't work any more with Ivy. What worked with me though is `ng.getOwningComponent($0)`.

- Inspect an element inside the looked-for component.
- While element is still selected, type `ng.getOwningComponent($0)` in the console.